# Popular tabela no sql server com dados vindos de uma planilha excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Como eu crio um script ou via `DTS`, uma forma de popular uma tabela no `sql server 2014`, com informações provenientes de uma planilha do `excel`? A planilha tem várias colunas, mas somente duas colunas serão populadas, sendo que duas outras colunas me informam o código do funcionário e do procedimento, para que seja populada de forma correta.

Comment: Botão direito em cima do seu banco -> tarefas-> Importar Dados. Na janela que abrir clique em avençar e escolha a fonte de dados como Microsoft Excel

Comment: @JefersonAlmeida, não é bem assim. Como eu disse anteriormente é o seguinte: Na planilha tenho o campo DT_Proc  e Num_Proc. Esses campos serão populados. Há também um campo que é o ID_Func. Por esse campo eu preciso preciso fazer um join com outra tabela para popular, já que a tabela que será populada não tem esse campo. Ou seja, preciso "joinar" duas tabelas para popular uma terceira. Esse é o imbrolho que passo.

Comment: Da maneira q eu disse vc vai criar uma tabela nova com todos os dados do excel e através dessa tabela nova, vc pode fazer todos os seus joins para popular sua verdadeira tabela, ao final do processo vc apaga a tabela que foi criada a partir do excel.

Comment: Voce diz criar uma temp? E popular tudo com excel e depois popular a outra tabela?

Comment: Isso mesmo, dessa forma fica muito mais fácil para vc tratar seus dados

Answer (score 1):

Você poderá fazer um `select` diretamente em sua planilha:
*(Será necessário executar as configurações iniciais com o **sp_configure**)*

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
reconfigure

exec sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1 
reconfigure

SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.ACE.OleDB.12.0', 
                          'EXCEL 8.0;Database=C:\importacao.xlsx',
                          Planilha1$)
```

No select acima, o [`OPEMROWSET`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190312.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) se comportará como uma tabela, portanto, poderá fazer o que quiser, inclusive popular a tabelas com os campos que deseja.

```
SELECT COD_FUN, COD_PROCEDIMENTO INTO TabelaTeste
FROM OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.ACE.OleDB.12.0', 
                 'EXCEL 8.0;Database=C:\importacao.xlsx',
                 Planilha1$)
```

**Requisitos**

- O Servidor (onde o SQL Server está instalado) deve ter acesso a pasta onde está seu arquivo Excel; No exemplo acima, "C:\" é diretamente a raiz do servidor.
- Verifique qual *Provider* você tem instalado:

[image: Microsoft.ACE.OleDB.12.0]